# Going to CSS class in vim

Tags: vim, macvim

In Sublime Text 2 I used to hit `command + t` and type in the CSS class I had to go to. How can I do that in vim?

Answer (score 0):

Use forward search: `/myclass` then `<Enter>` or backward search: `?myclass` then `<Enter>`.

Use `n` to jump to next match or `N` to jump to previous match.

Add `set incsearch` to your `~/.vimrc` for even quicker movement.

See `:help search-commands` for more.

`:help motion.txt` will blow your mind.